# Magento shop really slow TTFB waiting time

Tags: performance, magento

i have a customer, which magento webshop is extremely slow. As you can see on the screenshot, TTFB is about 20 seconds. I have contacted the hosting company, which says its a external problem, and not something with their servers, but is that correct ?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following step may help you out,

1. Installation of full cache extension
2. merge css and js file,

3 optimize product images

4. enable caching
5. disable logging

etc

Answer (score 0):

To find the problem of slow loading, you must enable a profiling in settings of Magento: System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Profiler
https://gyazo.com/6ee76548f3e706b3ab74e2f8af715a1d
above specify your IP in the field Allowed IPs.

After that, restart page and you will see below profiler.
https://gyazo.com/5ec23b33c38295c76bce55fbd18cc46f
You can see in a column «time» in what part of code lost a significant part of the resources or copy it in your question and we will try to give better answer by optimization